# What more do I need than SSL? Why

Tags: api, rest, authentication, ssl

I'm in the middle of creating a RESTful API for a personal project and I've been reading about api authentication. It is probable that I just don't understand what different things are for. What is OAuth for? What are API keys for?

**Main Question**

Why can't I just have every request use HTTPS and use sessions/cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users will access your API through an application you own or control, then HTTPS and user authentication/authorization is ok.

However, if you want to allow applications created by other developers to access your API OAuth and API keys allow you to control how these third party applications use your APIs.

- **API keys**: By assigning individual api keys to each application, you can identify the application sending the request. You can use this information to track or limit what the application can do with your APIs.
- **OAuth**: If the 3rd party application needs to access sensitive data owned by users or perform an operation on their behalf, then you want to ensure the user is ok with this. One way you can do this is to require the application to pass the user credentials with every request. However, this is usually not a good idea as you don't want users to reveal their usernames and passwords to third parties. Here is where OAuth comes to the rescue as it allows users to provide third parties with limited permissions to access your API on their behalf.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is adequate for this if:

- you require a client certificate
- the application obtains the client certificate
- the application validates it against a list of acceptable clients
- the application records which client executed the transaction.

Without all that you're just accepting transactions from just anybody, which is the problem that OAuth is solving.